# jwplayer-rails gem - how to show multiple videos?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, jwplayer

I want to create a page with some video previews using jwplayer-rails gem.

The problem is that I can see only one video - the last rendered.
I want to show the "current" video as bigger (it is the "multimedium" class) and 6 others smaller below ("recommended-video" class)

```
<%= jwplayer_assets %>
<h4><%= @multimedium.title %></h4>
<div class="multimedium">
   <%= jwplayer({file: @multimedium.link, width: 474, height: 270, stretching:'fill' }) %>
</div>

<% @recommended.each do |video| %>
   <div class="col-md-6 recommended-video">
     <div><%= jwplayer({file: video.link, width: 225, height: 126, stretching:'fill' }) %></div>
     <p class="title"><%= link_to "#{video.title}", video %></p>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

In my controller I have

```
@recommended = Multimedium.recommended.last(6)
```

It renders the good objects - I can see it from the titles. But even in the show action where the bigger video is the one I clicked the title is correct but not the video.

I know there is the option to create a playlist but it's not something I need.

Have you ever had this problem?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Hm, I have never used a rails gem before for our player, where did you download it from? Do you have a link to the embed attempt?

Comment: here is the link for the gem: [link](https://github.com/choix/jwplayer-rails)

Comment: This isn't something we made here. Do you have an example of where you embedded the player on your site?

Comment: Unfortunately I don''t have it yet on a site which is available online. But in the end I started with using the scripts instead of the gem. Problem solved!

Comment: Ah, glad you got it.